# asp.net mvc 3 a condition always return false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a UserManager Model.it's looks like:

```
public class UserManager
{
    private ToLetDBEntities TLE = new ToLetDBEntities();
    public string GetUserPassword(string usermail)
    {
        var user = from o in TLE.users where o.email_add == usermail select o;
        if (user.ToList().Count > 0)
        {
            return user.First().password;

        }
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and i've a AccountController like:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(UserLogOn model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserManager um = new UserManager();
            string pass = um.GetUserPassword(model.email_add);

            if (model.password==pass)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.email_add, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The  provided  password is incorrect.");

            }

        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and i've a UserLogon Model contains(email_add,password). When i run this controller its always gives me "The  provided  password is incorrect" error message. if(model.password==pass) this condition always gives false. please anyone help me.Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Is your stored password from GetUserPassword() hashed or encrypted?

Comment: You need to do some simple debugging... i.e. in GetUserPassword, does user == null or does it come back with a user... if a user comes back - what is his password property value?

Comment: password is simply nchar type in database. i've check that password that return is not null or empty.

Comment: Well nchar fields are padded in SQL Server.

Comment: @Tuan,sorry, i do not understand  the padded!

Comment: It means that SQL Server fills the column with spaces up to the maximum column length. For example, if the column is type nchar(15) and the stored value is 'secret', it will store it as 'secret^^^^^^^^^' (^ represents a blank space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some simple debugging.

I.e.

- in GetUserPassword, does user == null or does it come back with a user?
- if a user comes back - what is their password property value?

UPDATE: From comments

Because you are using nchar(15) as the database column type, the string that comes from the database will be padded with extra white space.

You could fix the issue by trimming the password when you return it - like so:

```
return user.First().password.Trim();
```

But the better fix would be to use nvarchar for the database column type and then you wouldn't have the whitespace padding problem.

BONUS: In the GetUserPassword method, you are enumerating the `user` IQueryable collection twice - this will result in two DB calls.

Change it to something like this to avoid that:

```
public class UserManager
{
    private ToLetDBEntities TLE = new ToLetDBEntities();
    public string GetUserPassword(string usermail)
    {
        var user = TLE.users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.email_add == usermail);
        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.password;

        }
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried this in UserManager:  <code>string pass = um.GetUserPassword(model.email_add);
                if (pass == null || pass.Length == 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");

                } </code>         it Gives Same Error.

Comment: See my update. Also, instead of doing `if (pass == null || pass.Length == 0)` you could do `if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(pass))`